# Which anime are these images from?

Tags: story-identification, anime

Does any one know which anime these images are from?

[image]

Comment: Welcome, you've shown no evidence that this question is on-topic here. Can you in anyway prove that this anime has something to do with Science Fiction or Fantasy?

Comment: A textbook example worthy of Anime SE's "Why did we ban identification questions?"

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on the T&A SE.  Oh wait...

Comment: Saucy looking girls in swimsuits are fantastic, but not ***fantastical***. Off-topic, I'm afraid, unless you can offer any more pics or a bit of video.

Comment: @Steve-O - Now there's a proposal on Area 51 that many would endorse. What kind of questions would they answer though?

Comment: @Valorum first image she has a halo

Comment: @Valorum Well, for starters, I imagine it would be **strictly** photo ID questions... No photo? Off-topic.

Comment: @Steve-O  -  whatever would I do without Urban Dictionary?

Comment: @Himarm - I thought it was a light fixture.

Comment: you could probably ask the guy whose instagram the first image was taken from though

Comment: @Gallifreyan have a better life?

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ  -  dunno. I'll probably forget it by tomorrow

Comment: This is from the opening sequence of a video game called *Senran Kagura: Estival Versus* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kghk7WRxa0Q – first picture at 49 seconds, second picture at 42 seconds. (It's a fighting game where the fighters lose pieces of their clothing when they're hit … But I guess it could *barely* be said to have a fantasy setting of sorts.)

Comment: @Gallifreyan We actually used to get four or five a day like this over on Anime. We had a smaller scale ban on image-only id questions before the big ban.

Comment: @Torisuda - Our policy is far laxer/friendlier.

Comment: @Valorum I'm aware. I'm glad it's working for you.

Comment: @tobiasvl  -  yep, that's the worst thing I ever watched.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Yeah, it's something… But thanks for the reopen anyway ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Senran Kagura: Estival Versus

These images are not from an anime, but from the opening sequence of a Japanese video game called *Senran Kagura: Estival Versus*.

The opening cinematic can be seen here:

The first image appears at 49 seconds, and the second at 42 seconds.

It's a fighting game where hitting your (female) opponent rips apart their clothing, but the game does have a fantasy setting (although the other games in the series are arguably more clear-cut fantasy). Courtesy of the [Senran Kagura wiki](http://senrankagura.wikia.com/wiki/Senran_Kagura:_Estival_Versus), here's the background story:

> The flame that burns twice as bright burns half as long, and so it is with the lives of young shinobi. Death comes swiftly — for the lucky ones — and, for those still living, grief is a constant companion. Ryōbi and Ryōna, two shinobi sisters of the Hebijo Clandestine Girls’ Academy elite, know that truth all too well, and they mourn their beloved elder sister every day.
>
> But, when a mystical phenomenon appears, drawing the shinobi world’s finest young ladies into a parallel dimension, everything they know about life and death turns upside down. Taken to a strange world resembling a warm summer island, the girls find themselves face to face with their departed loved ones.
>
> The island’s mysterious mistresses challenge the girls, who hail from four rival schools, to a contest of strength and wits. The winning school, she promises, will not only learn the highest secrets of shinobi lore, but will also have the honour of laying their loved ones’ souls to rest.
>
> The buxom beauties prepare for a new kind of battle, facing not only their rivals, but questions galore. Can the island's hosts be trusted? Will the other schools play fair, team up, or cheat? Will there be time to enjoy the beach before the fighting starts? Will anyone manage to keep their clothes intact? And… if they win, can they bear to be parted from their loved ones a second time?

Comment: Obviously a fighting game from that introduction! :D